# In "The One" (2001), why would they want to send Gabriel Yulaw to Hades Universe?

Tags: the-one

During the movie, we learn that if either Gabriel Yulaw or Gabe Law dies, the other will become 'The One', which is why when Roedecker and Funsch decided to split into two, one would kill Yulaw, whilst the other would get ready to finish Gabe Law.

> Roedecker: *(with a small bomb in his hand)* When the green light [of your watch] turns red and stays steady, and Yulaw is dead-...
>
> Funsch: And you.
>
> Roedecker: You know what to do.
>
> Funsch: *(loads his handgun)* Not a problem.

Yulaw also used that knowledge to convince Roedecker and Funsch not to kill him during the hospital attack.

> Yulaw: *(with two guns pointed at him)* We all know, if you kill me, you have to kill the other guy.

From the very beginning of the movie to the end, the objective of the MVA (Multiverse Authority) is to catch and send Yulaw to the Hades Universe (which they succeeded, thanks to Gabe's help).

However, on the end, following his fight against Gabe, Yulaw was fairly weakened. And when he was sent to the Hades Universe, a horde of hundreds (if not thousands) of people started rushing him for a seemingly long (if not endless) fight.

Doesn't it mean that they sent him to his death, despite knowing that he was the last one aside Gabe Law? If he does die swarmed by the Hades people, Gabe Law is going to become The One. Even if we consider that he's a reasonable person, that's not a reasonable thing to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The other person's *death* isn't the catalyst for the transfer of energy but rather **that a person from another universe has to be the proximate cause of their violent death.**

> Once he was forced to defend himself against himself in another universe. **Killed him. In doing so, part of the other life's energy transferred to him.**
>
> Made him stronger. Made all of you stronger.
>
> **Each time he kills one of you, the energy divides** among the survivors.

Gabe Law doesn't seem to be at risk of becoming "The One" if his *other self* dies as a result of randomly fighting or else everyone in the multiverse would have a 1:125 chance of being the last man standing and becoming a god.

Comment: Would their hypothetical killing of Yulaw during the hospital attack be somehow linked to Gabe then?

Comment: @Clockwork - That's a good question. I'd assume it's like Highlander where the universe somehow knows which one did the deed and rewards them accordingly. Note that there's some bleedover to Gabe Law (as his numbers dwindle) but the fact that Gabriel is clearly the more powerful strongly suggests that the energy isn't being *evenly* distributed

Comment: About the 1:125 chance of being the last man standing, I don't think there's exactly 125 universes. I think there was 125 universes with alternative "Yulaw". Remember when Funsch mentioned that in an universe Gabe didn't exist? Maybe he was pointing out one among an infinite possibility.

Comment: @Clockwork - The script and treatment talk about a new universe being created each time there's a black hole created in the datum universe. The implies a *limited* number of universes rather than an infinite number

Answer (score 0):

If Yulaw dies, no matter at whose hands, that energy is transferred.  Never once does the movie say anything about it needing to be yourself who kills him, just that if they die the energy is split amongst the survivors. In fact Yulaw and the guards prove this fact by Yulaw stating it:

> Yulaw: (with two guns pointed at him) We all know, if you kill me, you have to kill the other guy.

New universes are constantly created through black holes forming.to be the one requires in my opinion continually hunting down new gabes. By not hunting them down, it will create balance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I'm not sure this answers the question why they sent Gabriel to the Hades Universe.  If this is a response to the other answer, you should wait until you have earned enough reputation to comment on it.